# how to store an image on Google Cloud Storage sent by Android using Python

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, app-engine-ndb

I want to do the following:

1. using cURL and uploading an image onto a Blobstore or Google Cloud Storage. **But, the session is not kept between two cURL calls** (My guess)

AppEngine needs to generate an URI I can use to store the image (my guess)

```
curl -i http://localhost:8082/upload_form
```

The executed code is

```
class PhotoUploadFormHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload_photo')
        # The method must be "POST" and enctype must be set to "multipart/form-data".
        self.response.out.write('***' + upload_url + '***')

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/upload_form', PhotoUploadFormHandler),], debug=True)
```

The output is the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
cache-control: no-cache
Content-Length: 115
Server: Development/2.0
Date: Fri, 06 Jun 2014 08:52:17 GMT

***http://localhost:8082/_ah/upload/ahNkZXZ-ZXZlbnRzcHVsc2UtZGV2ciILEhVfX0Jsb2JVcGxvYWRTZXNzaW9uX18YgICAgIDYtQoM***
```

Then I perform a cURL using the new URL:

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -F "file=@./photofeed.png" http://localhost:8082/_ah/upload/ahNkZXZ-ZXZlbnRzcHVsc2UtZGV2ciILEhVfX0Jsb2JVcGxvYWRTZXNzaW9uX18YgICAgIDovQoM
```

Here is the output of the command :

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fcb65021000
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fcb65021000) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 8082 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8082 (#0)
> POST /_ah/upload/ahNkZXZ-ZXZlbnRzcHVsc2UtZGV2ciILEhVfX0Jsb2JVcGxvYWRTZXNzaW9uX18YgICAgIDovQoM HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:8082
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 2999
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------76b075a1768d
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Length: 254
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
* Server Development/2.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: Development/2.0
< Date: Fri, 06 Jun 2014 08:54:38 GMT
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
< 
<html>
 <head>
  <title>404 Not Found</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>404 Not Found</h1>
  The resource could not be found.<br /><br />
No such upload session: ahNkZXZ-ZXZlbnRzcHVsc2UtZGV2ciILEhVfX0Jsb2JVcGxvYWRTZXNzaW9uX18YgICAgIDovQoM


 </body>
* Closing connection 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found partially the answer here : [Using the Blobstore API with Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage)

I need to create specifically the image into the Google Cloud Storage and I have changed the CreateFile method into a CreateImage method

```
def CreateImage(imageName, imageData): 
    """Create a GCS file with GCS client lib.

    Args:
      filename: GCS filename.

    Returns:
      The corresponding string blobkey for this GCS file.
    """
    # Create a GCS file with GCS client.
    with gcs.open(imageName, 'w') as f:
        f.write(imageData)

    # Blobstore API requires extra /gs to distinguish against blobstore files.
    blobstore_filename = '/gs' + imageName
    # This blob_key works with blobstore APIs that do not expect a
    # corresponding BlobInfo in datastore.
    return blobstore.create_gs_key(blobstore_filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the upload url already expired? It's only valid for a couple of minutes.

See also:
[google app engine; upload to blobstore gives 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157591/google-app-engine-upload-to-blobstore-gives-404-error)

Comment: this isn't the case as I perform the POSTs immediately