# Error 404 when image is uploaded to blob store while working locally

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am  new to the python app engine development an tried running https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Complete_sample_application source code.

but after choosing the image file and clicking submit i get ;

```
    404 Not Found

The resource could not be found.
```

The problem is similar to this one [google app engine; upload to blobstore gives 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157591/google-app-engine-upload-to-blobstore-gives-404-error?rq=1)

but even before the ["10 minute" time out](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore#create_upload_url) i still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with the sample app. You're running in to two of them. The visible one (the 404) is that there isn't an `upload_failure.html`. That's downstream of the real problem, which is that the app wants you to be logged in.

The quick workaround is to visit http://localhost:8080/_ah/login to log in. (Click the Login button.) It'll leave you on that page, so navigate manually to http://localhost:8080/ and continue with the demo. It should work now.

Comment: I've filed an Issue against the problem, and will submit a pull request with a fix.